# Install R-3.6.0 on my local directory in Linux environment

Tags: r, linux, zlib, configure

Since I do not have a root account, I want to install the newest R (3.6.0) to my local directory. I downloaded a R-3.6.0.tar.gz file and save it to **$HOME/Programs**.

After

```
$ tar xvf R-3.6.0.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.6.0
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programs/R
```

I had some error like

```
checking if zlib version >= 1.2.5... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

So I got the newest zlib library (zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz) to **$HOME/Programs**, and then

```
$ tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
$ cd zlib-1.2.11
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programs/zlib-1.2.11
$ make && make install
```

This works perfectly, but after this when I tried to configure R($ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programs/R) again, it still produces the same problem.

```
checking if zlib version >= 1.2.5... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

I think this problem might be related to the PATH in my .bash_profile(currently it is set as PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin).

I am completely new to Linux environment and bash commands, so it would be grateful if you could provide some detailed demonstration.

Comment: *"still produces a problem"* ... what is the problem?

Comment: *"This works perfectly, but still produces the same problem when I tried to configure R"* - Forgive my ignorance... What works perfectly? Or if things are working perfectly, then why do you have a problem? Perhaps you should clearly state what the problem is.

Comment: @jww I changed that part totally, sorry for misleading context. 
Installing zlib was successful, but still installing R makes the same problem

Comment: You have to tell R‘s configure where it can find zlib.